# How to attach extra data to a WebSocket connection so I can do clean up on disconnect

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

I am using `npm ws` as my WebSocket server using this implementation:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const server = https.createServer({
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./cert.pem"),
  key: fs.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
});
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server, clientTracking: true });
```

And here are my listeners:

```
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
  console.log("connection");

  ws.on("close", function close(ws) {
    console.log("disconnect");
  });

  ws.on("message", function incoming(message) {
    console.log("INBOUND MESSAGE: %s", message);
    obj = JSON.parse(message);

    switch (obj.action) { ....
```

I am using the socket server to set up a card game. I am able to attach the `ws` connection coming from `on("message` to an object (e.g., `player[id].ws = ws`) and I'm able to use that attached data to send messages (e.g., `ws.send(player[id].ws, ____);`)

The challenge I have is when a connection drops, I need to clean up all the game data surrounding the player, (game data, player data, etc).  However, when the `"close"` listener fires, the `ws` data does not have any data in it so I can identify who dropped and clean up the data?

I would like to be able to `on("message"` set `ws.playerId='ksjfej` so when I get the `ws("close"` I can use `ws.playerId` to clean up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you don't realize, but inside the `close` event the `ws` variable that represents the connection is entirely within scope as long as you remove the `ws` parameter you mistakenly declared from the callback.  So, this will work.

```
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
  console.log("connection");

  // change this callback signature to remove the `ws`
  ws.on("close", function(/* no ws here */) {
    console.log("disconnect");
    // you can reference the `ws` variable from a higher scope here
    // you just have to remove it from the function parameter list here
    // because it isn't passed to the event itself.
    console.log(ws);   // this will get ws from the higher scope
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly, I assign the `playerId` at connection and I'm able to clean everything else up on `"close"`.  I wonder why in the `npm ws` documentation they redeclare `ws` instead of letting it flow through.  Regardless, thanks friend00!

Comment: @WilWells - I don't see where the npm ws documentation redeclares `ws` as a close event argument.  I'm not sure where you're seeing that.

Comment: You're right. I must have mistyped it when I was building it.  Thanks again.